# QGIS QFieldSync project cannot copy layers in config settings

Tags: qgis, qfield, copy, configuration

In this one particular project which I tried to recreate from another project that will not sync with QField but just crashes QGIS. When I try to configure the project for QField packaging I only see the options for offline editing, no action and remove. I have reference layers that I just want to copy but that is not an option. The other (corrupted) project has all the options as expected. What is going on?